# SQL: clone table with partial data and all structure

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to clone a table in sql with partial data but with all structure (index, etc). This is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
CREATE TABLE "new table" (LIKE "old table")

INSERT INTO "new table" 
    SELECT * 
    FROM "old table"
    WHERE "date column" > ('now'::text::date - '1 year'::interval)
```

The error message says `INSERT` is wrong. When I execute only with `LIKE` it works, but when I try to input the data it doesn't.

Furthermore, the `WHERE` function is also correctly working.

Also, when I use CREATE TABLE "" AS it works and brings only the data without the structure. When I use LIKE it works and brings the structure without data. But, when I try to bring both data and structure it doesn't work and that is my question.

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using?

Comment: Please do NOT SPAM Tags. They are to be used to gather the relevant audience for your question and not an angry mod. Please add back only the DBMS you are using

Comment: thank you all for the attention, i'm using postgre

Answer (score 0):

It needs a `;` after the create statement, to close it before the insert.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE "old table" (
>  "date column" date
> );
> insert into "old table" ( "date column" ) values 
>  ('now'::date - '1 month'::interval);
> ```

**Without `;`**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE "new table" (LIKE "old table")
>
> INSERT INTO "new table" 
>     SELECT * 
>     FROM "old table"
>     WHERE "date column" > ('now'::date - '1 year'::interval)
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
> LINE 3: INSERT INTO "new table"
> ```

**With `;`**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE "new table" (LIKE "old table");
>
> INSERT INTO "new table" 
>     SELECT * 
>     FROM "old table"
>     WHERE "date column" > ('now'::date - '1 year'::interval)
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from "new table"
> ```
>
> ```
> | date column |
> | :---------- |
> | 2021-12-07  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=323e1325a08f39016a505c4ff70956f9)*